# Survey monkey c# console integration

Tags: surveymonkey

Please anyone provide some examples on c# Survey monkey integration console application?

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can paste the code in the question. Then select the text and click on the code block button.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking specifically on how to make API requests with C#? Or How to use the SurveyMonkey API.

The docs for the SurveyMonkey API can be found [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/). Just from doing some searching online, there is documentation on how to make web API requests in C# [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).

There is an SDK for using the SurveyMonkey API in C# I've seen people use available [here](https://github.com/bcemmett/SurveyMonkeyApi-v3).

Hopefully any of those links can help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for ur time and suggestions.I am looking for example code like how make survey monkey api requests with c#.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SurveyMonkeyApi](https://github.com/bcemmett/SurveyMonkeyApi-v3/blob/master/Examples.md) NuGet package.